# A short grin was smiled into Papa’s spoon. what is going on here?

Tags: rhetorical-devices

> A short grin was smiled into Papa’s spoon.

what is the device here?
is the grin personified?
is it past continuous as well?

Comment: Bit of context might help. Also, use capitals when needed.

Comment: I'll just add that this sentence appears to be taken from "The Joy of Cigarettes" section in Part 2 of "The Book Thief" by Markus Zusak

Comment: What is going on? Is someone smiling at a spoon? Is the smile being reflected in the spoon? It is unidiomatic (as "he smiled a grin" is unidiomatic) but isn't obviously a figure of speech, it reads like an awkward translation.

Comment: This seems to be the passive voice version of _[Someone] smiled a short grin (into Papa's spoon)._ I don't know why the writer has opted for this construction, though. It sure sounds awkward.

Comment: Thank you everyone!